# Keyboard Pull up layout

Tags: android

When i clicked on an EditText my layout pull up as shown in the image below.

![enter image description here][1]

My solution is to put a condition to check when the keyboard is shown or hide.

I use the following code

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
      Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

but how can i checked if **OFF**

```
 imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

and **ON**

```
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 1); is on ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this code in the manifest. This works for me:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Adding this to your `manifest` will not allow layout to go up with the keyboard, when `edittext` is focused.

Comment: Well very good, can you explain why down vote. I have edited my answer see if it helps you.

Comment: @Dimitri Ok, no prm. Did my answer helped you in getting your problem fixed?

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" and
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" has no effect on my layout

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```